# CSharp scripting, is it possible to return a value from a script run with csi.exe?

Tags: c#, csx

I'd like to create a script like this:

```
static int Main(string[] args)  
{
    if ( !File.Exists( @"E:\Ivara\Cache\TimeCacheLastUpdated.txt" ) )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 6;
}
```

And run it like this and get the error level:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csi.exe" E:\build\CruiseControl\bin\TestLoggingConfigExists.csx
```

ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you're running will be `csi.exe` and so `%ERRORLEVEL%` will reflect the exit code of that program (i.e. zero in case of successful compilation, non-zero otherwise), and not the script that it runs.

Couple of options that come to mind:

1. Use `csc.exe` instead to generate an executable application from your script. Run that and capture its exit code.
2. If for some reason all this needs to happen in one shot, create a small app that takes the script path as input argument, spawns `csc.exe` to generate executable, run it, and marshal its exit code. (or use an in-memory compilation + execution alternative: https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/12/in-memory-c-sharp-compilation-using-roslyn)

Answer (score 2):

*Edit 2: much simpler this time*

Passing the exit code to Environment.Exit at the end of the script does the job.

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    if ( !File.Exists( @"E:\Ivara\Cache\TimeCacheLastUpdated.txt" ) )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 6;
}

// csi.exe normally ignores the exit code from Main, but we can terminate
// the csi.exe process abruptly, and forward the exit code to the caller.
Environment.Exit(Main(Args.ToArray()));
```